# MKMapKit Framework in iOS I need pay?

Tags: ios, mapkit

Hi I need develop an iOS app that use `MKMapKit` Framework and I need add Annotations and the question is, this has any cost? I don't know if I need buy a key for use this framework.

Answer (score 0):

no, you don't need a key for it afaik. I've been using maps in my apps for years and never got a bill for it. You could probably find this out with google.

Answer (score 0):

Using MapKit in iOS will not cost you anything. You may need to pay someone else to get data to make your annotations, but that won't be Apple. If you're developing for iOS 6 or later you won't have any connection to Google and it would actually be a violation of their terms & conditions to use Google's data on a non-Google map